# Difference printf formatting for string/date/integer in unix?

Tags: string, unix, printf, quotes, ksh

can anyone explain to me the difference between `'"%s"\n'`, `"%s\n"`, `"%d\n"` and `"%F\n"`? If i want a string between quotes is it correct this one? `'"%s"\n'` and without quotes? Sorry but i can't understand. The shell is ksh. Thanks

Comment: Haven't you googled a little bit before posting the question? There are a lot of good references in the web. For example this one http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf . Also it is good to try yourself instead of just asking * If i want a string between quotes is it correct this one?*. That is, show some effort on your research. See this as a general comment about how you will get good help in this site.

Comment: Really sorry, i tried to search on google but maybe in a wrong way. However thanks for the answere.